# How to make each row the same height according to the tallest content in each row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to set the height of each row to be equal according to the tallest content in each individual row.

For example doing:

```
c-column {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Won't work as the first row would grow to tall.
I have this markup as I need to make the columns responsive on mobile

```css
.c-table {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 10px #cccccc;
  background: transparent;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 40px;
 
}

.c-column>div {
  padding: 24px;
}

.c-column>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f2f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendreri</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? There are 4 columns as child of the whole table. These columns are equal in height. The contents of the columns are not related to each other. The children of `c-column` are now not related between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c-column elements are the grid children, so you can not make the grid rows adapt to the inner divs.

You can solve this changing the layout and removing the c-column elements.

Otherwise, you can get the same effect without changing the html, using display: contents;  - See snippet

```css
.c-table {
  display: grid;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 10px #cccccc;
  background: transparent;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  padding: 40px;
 
}

.c-column {
  display: contents; /* added */
}
.c-column>div {
  padding: 24px;
}

.c-column>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f2f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendreri</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-column">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in risus purus. Quisque ac leo pulvinar purus congue vestibulum. Integer hendrerit consectetur tortor quis interdum. Etiam ut porta enim. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out, when running the snippet you will see that the rows will be the height of the tallest item inside of it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.description {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}

.col {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```